# How to automate javascript web app even when website/browser isn't open

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, build-automation

I'm working on a javascript based web application. I have a webpage which has nothing but a button. When I click this button, it pulls data from another website and stores it in my Mongo database.

I need to automate this button click. That is, even without opening the website and clicking the button, the 'pulling data from another website and storing it in my database' should happen.

I literally do nothing but click a single button. So I believe this can be made automated and run automatically without human intervention at regular interval. (example: I need this process done everyday at 6 PM). Is this possible at all?

P.S: I've heard of Selenium but it isn't clear whether selenium would do this. Even if that's the case, I can't seem to use the tool. I was able to download a '.jar' file but it doesn't even open.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Why does a browser need to be involved at all?

Comment: Hi Pointy, I wanted to say that it is completely automated - Like this should happen even when I sleep. At regular interval. That's all I wanted to ask.

Comment: If you are using JavaScript in a browser and there is no window open I don't think that can be achieved. If you run JavaScript via Node (node.js) then there might be opportunities to make that happen.

I think you might be better using a server-side solution such as a cron job to run a php script to pull the data and save it.

Comment: OK so why not just set up some local service or cron job or whatever to hit the appropriate URL with `curl` or `wget` or something like that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't include that in the question. I run JS via Node only. I don't understand what cron job is and I don't know PHP. Any idea how this can be done using JS (node.js) alone?

Comment: Seems like I need to research about cron job. I'll check that out. Thank you people.

Answer (score 0):

You can almost certainly automated the click of a button with selenium, however, selenium works by opening a web browser and then interacting with different items as if it were a person.  This would work, although it may be more resource intensive than you want.

Have you though about setting up the data pull to run via a console command/something else, which you could then automate without dealing with a GUI?